# Tensorflow ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm facing this error when running my code with 3 lstm layers. Not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help. Here MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=250. After running the cost function, i get the error 'ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible'

```
# Generate a Tensorflow Graph
tf.reset_default_graph()
batch_size = 25
embedding_size = 50
lstmUnits = 64
max_label = 2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

number_of_layers=3

#  Embeddings to represent words
saved_embeddings = np.load('wordVectors.npy')
embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(saved_embeddings, x)

def lstm_cell():
  return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstmUnits,reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)

lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(number_of_layers)])

lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstmCell, output_keep_prob=0.75)

outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, embeddings, dtype=tf.float32)

predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], 1, activation_fn=tf.sigmoid)

cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
```

ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible 
full error message as below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-f261b46a6f62> in <module>()
1 # Try 3
----> 2 cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
3 cost
4 #y.shape
5 #y.reshape[]

/home/lavared/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py in mean_squared_error(labels, predictions, weights, scope, loss_collection, reduction)
564     predictions = math_ops.to_float(predictions)
565     labels = math_ops.to_float(labels)
--> 566     predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
567     losses = math_ops.squared_difference(predictions, labels)
568     return compute_weighted_loss(

/home/lavared/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)
751     """
752     if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
--> 753       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
754 
755   def most_specific_compatible_shape(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible
```

Comment: Please give full stack trace of the error and some way to figure out line numbers

Comment: Have you tried `cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, predictions[:, 0])` or `y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)` before `cost = ...`?

Comment: updated the full stack of error as above.

Comment: y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1) helped in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a month-old.

I was facing this issue some days ago. It was a well-known [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4715) even though they solved only for that specific case.

In your case, the only working solution I found is to modify:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
```

in:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 1])
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with my Tensorflow code, the problem seems to me is the understanding of the output dimension is not the dimension of the output array but the possibility of the output. For the example of MNIST 0-9 handwriting, the possibility is 10.